# in C++ why constructor initializer must be used if a class does not have default constructor?

Tags: c++, default-constructor

I somewhere read that if I have a base class(A) member in another class(B), constructor initializer must be used if A does not have default constructor.

Why constructor initializer must be used in this class ? Will there be any performance improvement if this is done ?

```
  #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int );
};

A::A(int arg) {
    i = arg;
    cout << "A's Constructor called: Value of i: " << i << endl;
}

// Class B is derived from A
class B: A {
public:
    B(int );
};

B::B(int x):A(x) { //Initializer list must be used
    cout << "B's Constructor called";
}

int main() {
    B obj(10);
```

Comment: The default constructor can be called without parameters, for everything else you must pass some values. It has nothing to do with performance.

Comment: How else would you initialize the object?  It can't be default-initialized without a default constructor.

Comment: Below is the case. 

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
 
class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int );
};
 
A::A(int arg) {
    i = arg;
    cout << "A's Constructor called: Value of i: " << i << endl;
}
 
// Class B is derived from A
class B: A {
public:
    B(int );
};
 
B::B(int x):A(x) { //Initializer list must be used
    cout << "B's Constructor called";
}
 
int main() {
    B obj(10);

A takes one argument

Answer (score 4):

A subclass's constructor will always call one of the superclass's constructors. If you don't explicitly state which one should be called, the default constructor will be called. If the superclass does not have a default constructor, this isn't possible, so the code won't compile.

> Why constructor initializer must be used in this class ?

Because without a default constructor the compiler doesn't have a superclass constructor that it can call implicitly (the non-default constructors require arguments and the compiler can't just make up which arguments to use).

> Will there be any performance improvement if this is done ?

The code will compile. If you don't do this, it won't.

Comment: Thanks. I have edited the question with an example. Here A has a user defined ctor which takes an argument.